# Setting properties in Spring

Tags: spring, properties, edit

Is there a way to change the properties of a file? I'm trying to run selenium tests in parallel, with Spring and Jetty, so I'm trying to configure the url of the database, the port of the jettyserver and the port of the selenium server. So that I'm able to initialize two or more servers where the tests can run on.

My server.properties file contains this:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/bibliothouris_scenario
jetty.port=8081
seleniumServer.port=4444
```

I can read those properties with a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, and I need the database URL, jettyport and seleniumserver port to be flexible.

I have declared them like this:

In my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:server.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

In the serverContext.xml file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:server.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.~companyName~.bibliothouris.jetty.JettyServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="${jetty.port}" />
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteControlConfiguration">
            <property name="port" value="${seleniumServer.port}" />
            <property name="singleWindow" value="true" />
            <property name="timeoutInSeconds" value="10" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor">
            <constructor-arg value="localhost" />
            <constructor-arg value="${seleniumServer.port}" />
            <constructor-arg value="*firefox c:/~companyname~/firefox/firefox.exe" />
            <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:${jetty.port}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When I change the data in server.properties the selenium tests run on the right servers with the right ports, without failures.

So now I'm looking for a method to change the properties in the server.properties file.

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, without your info, I couldn't find my own solution. Here it is:

```
try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
            "C:\\~CompanyName~\\workspace\\bibliothouris\\infrastructure\\src\\main\\resources\\server.properties");
        props.load(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();
        props.setProperty("seleniumServer.port", "4445");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            "C:\\~CompanyName~\\workspace\\bibliothouris\\infrastructure\\src\\main\\resources\\server.properties");
        props.store(fileOutputStream, "");
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've wrote this piece of code in a testclass, now I have to create a method of it, which takes a few arguments (the URL, jettyport and seleniumport). And I have to change the path to a relative one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Walle, please upvote the answers which helped, we are also here for the reputation ;)

Comment: I need 15 reputation to do that :D

Comment: Mat is right, you should access classpath resources via getResourceAsStream, otherwise your code will break when executed in a different environment

Comment: I've made a static method of it, but the problem is that I can't call getClass() in it. I've fixed it this way:

Comment: `private final static String FILENAME = "../infrastructure/src/main/resources/testserver.properties";` and `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);` it works properly right now. The code doesn't need to be executed from another environment, this project is just for getting an idea about parallel testing. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: You don't need getClass(), you can also use a class literal, e.g. MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...)

Comment: Well, I had some problems with refreshing the file after a test (he changed the ports and server when a test is finished), so I used a PropertiesConfiguration to fix it. So I guess I don't need the MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...). But thanks for the help, I'll remember it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by having a flag in my build process (I'm using Maven) that chose which property file to include in the final war. This way you can include different artifacts (different property files) with different properties without having to mess with the low level property support of Spring.

If you do need to do this is Spring only, I would recommend going for a Java based configuration, where you can get and set the properties by in code not in XML.

Comment: I'm using Maven as well, but it is the first time I use it. I'll give it a try;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the
>   properties of a file?

No, but you could solve this in the following ways.

- Split the properties into jdbc.properties (for applicationContext.xml) and test.properties (for serverContext.xml)
- override server.properties via a src/test/resources resource
- use system properties in addition to server.properties (use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setSystemPropertiesMode for this)